# Admob mediation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-admob

I am currently using firebase_admob in one of my Flutter projects. I was just curious if AdMob mediation works with this package. If not is there any way to do AdMob mediation in flutter.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Even I am looking for the same.

Comment: @Abin Mittu did you guys find any solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579831/flutter-admob-ads-with-mediation