# Flutter. Admob ads with mediation

Tags: flutter, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, mobile-ad-mediation, firebase-admob

I've integrated https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob into my app and implemented `rewarded ads`. My problem now is that I'd like to use mediation via this plugin. The only thing is that I know (from developing Android apps and also it says in the Admob docs) that one needs to include the mediated networks' SDKs in the app.

Does this plugin even support mediation? I wasn't able to find anything relating to this.
Or does the mediation only come from the admob dashboard, just by setting up the add-unit with mediation and you're not really required to add the SDKs?

I couldn't find any adapters for this plugin, so ... don't really have anything to integrate in the app.

I'm very confused. Does anyone know how to use mediation or if it even works with the current firebase_admob` flutter plugin?

Comment: I'm facing the same confusion now,if you already sort this could you please list how to do this flutter app

Comment: Hi Sam. More than what is mentioned in the accepted answer below including the discussion I had in the comments with Arnav ... not sure what else I can tell you..

Comment: Hi  just followed the steps in below answer and end-up with this issue, if  you can please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325206/flutter-app-integrating-adcolony-with-mediation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `firebase_admob` and that dependency supports mediation. You you would like to add mediation there is a guide over here:

Android - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediate
iOS - https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediate

You can select the ad network you would like to integrate and read the steps on how to do so. Sometimes the documentation can be outdated so just make sure you cross-check the steps with the ad network you want to integrate on their github repo.

If you are integrating it for Android you have to add the dependencies in your app level `build.gradle` file and it will automatically install that particular ad networks SDK in your Flutter app.

If you are adding the same for iOS just install the `Cocoapod` for the ad network at the end of your `Podfile`.

Comment: So no need for flutter plugins for adapters and ad network sdks ? Integrating "native" (note the quotes) libraries will still work with the flutter plugin ?! o.O

Comment: @AndreiBogdan yes, it is handled by the plugin itself, and you need to setup the rest on the Admob dashboard ofcourse.

Comment: Then everything's clear ! Very cool! Thanks for the info ! Starting to integrate things right now ...

Comment: You're welcome. I had to break my head over a day or two to get it! lol

Comment: Thanks for doing the heavy lifting :D As a bonus questions ... any recommandations on which networks to mediate ? I've started including Facebook ... any other suggestions ? I'm really new to ads ... i have no clue what i'm doing. haha

Comment: I've used Adcolony and its doing great so far haha :). It has an amazing fill rate however I haven't reached my buyout threshold yet.

Comment: Ok. I'll add AdColony next. Should I prioritize AdColony before Facebook? 
I think these three should be enough to start. I'm worried about the fill-rate with only Admob ads. "buyout threshold" ... not sure what that is.

Comment: Every ad network has a threshold of usually $100 (Adcolony & Admob) that you need to accumulate before you can actually receive money. Also don't worry these 3 are more than enough and will give you good fill rates in most countries! :)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks again ! Good luck with your own thing and take care !

Comment: @ArnavVaryani How did you integrate adcolony? They don't have SDK for Flutter.

Comment: @MutluSimsek use this dependency - https://pub.dev/packages/adcolony_flutter