# Flutter App Integrating AdColony with Mediation

Tags: flutter, adcolony, firebase-admob

When setting up AdMob Mediation With Flutter (  firebase_admob: ^0.9.3+2) I'm getting the following error

Note: I have successfully set up the ADmob integration

I follow all the steps mentioned here :
[Integrating AdColony with Mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/adcolony)

as per step 3, this is my app/build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.1.4.1'

}
```

## ERROR

```
      FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[17.0.
  0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-
  measurement-sdk-api@[17.0.0], but play-services-measurement-sdk-api version was 17.1.0.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_admob' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ads@18.1.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@{strictly 17.0.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@{strictly 19.0.1}
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_analytics' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@16.5.
  0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony@4.1.4.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass@{strictly 19.0.1}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@{strictly 17.1.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ads@{strictly 18.1.1}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@{strictly 17.0.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk@{strictly 17.0.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony@{strictly 4.1.4.1}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@{strictly 19.0.1}

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
  uild.gradle file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

[Found this github issue Upgrade SDK version from 18.1.1 to 19.1.0](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2550)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the code to compile after changing the versions

this is my pubspec.yaml for firebase:

```
  #Firebase libary
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  firebase_remote_config: ^0.3.1
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.3+3
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.3+2
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.15
```

and android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.1.0.0' //latest version 4.1.4.1 not compatible with firebase_admob 0.9.3+2
}
```

[com.google.ads.mediation.adcolony releases](https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/com.google.ads.mediation.adcolony/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downgrading the AdColony mediation adapter, I managed to get it working by manually editing the file "flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.3+2\android\build.gradle", so it gets the latest version of the Admob Android SDK:

```
android {
    dependencies {
        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.1.0'
    }
}
```

I have published this a month ago to the Play Store, for an app with around 100.000 MAU, and had no issue so far...

Comment: Thank Ernesto. That's a local cache though so it means you need to do it manually after installing packages right?